# Deduzir quantidade dentro de um loop em PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte `Array()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [inventory_id] => 1
            [product_id] => 1
            [order_id] => 0
            [product_quantity] => 15 <--------
            [notify_quantity] => 1
            [total_price] => 690
            [others_price] => 33.9
            [media_price] => 48.26
            [supplier_id] => 1
            [product_type] => order
            [product_stock_date] => 2019-01-31 11:59:06
            [initial_stock] => 1
            [type] => E
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [inventory_id] => 4
            [product_id] => 1
            [order_id] => 0
            [product_quantity] => 10 <--------
            [notify_quantity] => 1
            [total_price] => 200
            [others_price] => 20
            [media_price] => 22
            [supplier_id] => 2
            [product_type] => purchase
            [product_stock_date] => 2019-02-22 15:22:50
            [initial_stock] => 0
            [type] => E
        )

)`
```

Note que eu tenho `product_quantity = 15 e 10`.

Tenho a `$product['qty'] = 20`. Esta é a quantidade que eu estou solicitando no momento da compra. Ou seja, eu tenho em estoque, porque somando todos são 25 no total de itens.

Logo, na hora de montar o loop, eu preciso deduzir então 15 itens do primeiro e 5 itens do segundo... neste caso, irá sobrar somente 5 itens no segundo `array()`. O problema é: como fazer isso?

O que eu tentei:

```
foreach($suppliers_products as $s_products){
    $qty = $s_products->product_quantity;
    echo "Qtd total ".$s_products->inventory_id." > ".$qty."<br><br<br>";
    if($qty >= $product['qty']){
        echo "achou total <br>";
    } else {
        $s = $product['qty'] - $qty;
        echo $s." < faltou > <br>"; 
        echo "<br><br><br>faltou ainda <br>";
    }
}
```

Considerando que $suppliers_products é o `array()` acima.

> Para deduzir no estoque, estou usando como referência PEPS - Primeiro
>   que entra, primeiro que sai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alterar os dados dentro do laço você deverá percorrer por referência.

```
foreach ($estoques as &$estoque) {
  // -----------------^
}
```

E assim implementar basicamente a lógica que você já fez:

```
foreach ($estoques as &$estoque) {

    if ($estoque->quantidade >= $quantidade) {
        $estoque->quantidade -= $quantidade;
        break;
    }

    $quantidade -= $estoque->quantidade;
    $estoque->quantidade = 0;
}
```

Por exemplo:

```
$estoques = [
    (object) ['id' => 1, 'quantidade' => 15],
    (object) ['id' => 2, 'quantidade' => 10],
];

print_r($estoques);

$quantidade = 20;

foreach ($estoques as &$estoque) {

    if ($estoque->quantidade >= $quantidade) {
        $estoque->quantidade -= $quantidade;
        break;
    }

    $quantidade -= $estoque->quantidade;
    $estoque->quantidade = 0;
}

print_r($estoques);
```

Inicialmente o *array* será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [quantidade] => 15
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [quantidade] => 10
        )

)
```

Depois do laço será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [quantidade] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [quantidade] => 5
        )

)
```